# Permission denied (publickey) during SSH using Git Bash on a Windows Machine

Tags: ssh, unix, openssh, digital-ocean

When I try to execute the command `ssh -vvv user@ip_address`, the last few lines of the outcome looks as below:

```
debug3: send packet: type 50

debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply

debug3: receive packet: type 51

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

user@ip_address: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have tried using Putty as well and verified the public key under `/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys`. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got it resolved. Tried the following steps:

1. Copied the folders under `/root/.ssh` to `/home/username/.ssh` .
2. Changed the permission of `.ssh` to 700 and the files under it to 644.
3. In the local machine, i did "conversions-->export openssh key" from putty gen in the screen displaying my public key, which was generated from putty gen earlier.
4. Copied the openssh key to `~/.ssh/` and then copied the file content to `id_rsa` under the same path,i.e. .ssh
5. Created a config file under .ssh , which looks like below :

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   Hostname ip_address of remote server
   User username
   PubKeyAuthentication yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```
6. And finally tried to connect using the command

   ```
   ssh -vvv username@remoteserver_ip_address
   ```

Comment: point 5. What did u call the config file?

Comment: Hi @PerG , Windows should already have a file called config, it was under my username path such as : /c/Users/username/.ssh/config